# concatenating array of integers in c

Tags: c

I have run into some trouble trying to concatenate an array of integers into one number.  I understand how to do this with single digit numbers (my code below), but what if I was prompting a user to enter 5 numbers and they entered 12, 345, 552, 126, 44.  I need to develop an algorithm that will take the users input and concatenate it to make one integer, like this 1234555212644

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int num[3]={1, 2, 3}, n1, n2, new_num;

    n1 = num[0] * 100;
    n2 = num[1] * 10;

    new_num = n1 + n2 + num[2];

    printf("%d \n", new_num);

    return 0;
}
```

output: 123

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Just loop through all the numbers in the array using `printf("%d", num[i]);` and at the very end output a new-line, and it will appear as if all the numbers in the array were concatenated.

Comment: `1234555212644` is too big for an integer.

Comment: I believe you can convert them into characters and them concatenate them using strcat(), which would save you the arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

@dreamlax's suggestion makes sense if you were only trying to print the integer, but if you've simplified your question and in fact you'd like to have the actual integer, you can use the logarithm to determine how many digits a number has:

```
int concat(int* arr, size_t len)
{
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        int digits = floor(log10(arr[i])) + 1;
        result *= pow(10, digits);
        result += arr[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here's [an Ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/BlPAsJ).

Indeed, however, you quickly run out of space to store such a large integer. If you require storage of such a large integer, you may want to consider using a char array and using `sprintf` in a loop to concatenate the digits, or a `stringstream`.

Comment: The question is tagged `c`, so `stringstream` is out of reach unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work for long numbers. There's no error checking here, it's for illustration.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    int num[] = {12, 345, 552, 126, 44};
    char buf[1000] = ""; // max size of number in digits - 1
    char n[10] = ""; // max size of individual number - 1

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(num)/sizeof(num[0]); i++) {
        sprintf(n, "%d", num[i]);
        strcat(buf, n);
    }

    printf("Number: %s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

You could also then easily assign the string number to a large integer (e.g. unsigned long long) using strtoll if wanted, and that function would also tell you if the number was too large to fit.

Comment: Rather than using `strcat`, you can write to `buf` directly and you can use the return value of `sprintf` (or better yet, use `snprintf`) to determine how much further to advance into `buf`. As it is now, `strcat` has to scan through the entire string every time you append a number, so the larger the numbers and the more numbers you have, the longer it will take for `strcat` to find the end of the string.